# Why I get a TypeError in this python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, coroutine

I want to use the writer in another process, but I get a error

here are my tcp server:

```
import asyncio
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager


def pro1(c):
    asyncio.run(main(c))


def pro2(c):
    while True:
        if len(c) != 0:
            print(c)


class Handler:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.connect_dict = c

    async def receive_handle(self, reader, writer):
        self.connect_dict.update({1: writer})


async def main(c):
    handler = Handler(c)
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handler.receive_handle, '0.0.0.0', 10100)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    connect_dict = manager.dict()
    p1 = Process(target=pro1, args=(connect_dict,))
    p2 = Process(target=pro2, args=(connect_dict,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

here are my tcp client

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('localhost', 10100))
```

here are the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\科研\燃料电池发动机远程监控软件\test2.py", line 20, in receive_handle
    self.connect_dict.update({1: writer})
  File "<string>", line 2, in update
  File "C:\Users\pingt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 795, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "C:\Users\pingt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Users\pingt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle TaskWakeupMethWrapper objects
```

Comment: You can not  send `writer` to other processes. It is not serializable.